# Bootstrap carousel not working, just images are displayed one by one

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

```html
 <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/1.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my code. This code just displays images one by one. The slide is not working.

Comment: Did you add Bootstrap carousel reference?

Comment: Actually I am working with angular 2 and I have added bootstrap and carousel modules.Anything else have to be added?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the references on your `html` like below code snippet.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/1.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This issue might be adding bootstrap to angular ? check this https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/ also be sure about the version of bootstrap which should have carousel.